# How do I prevent my observable subscription from running again for each emitted value?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable

I've got a lengthy bit of code with some nested subscriptions and transactions and such.

```
  updateActivity(value, index) {
    return this.currentDay.subscribe(docRef => {
      let dayRef = this.db.collection('days').doc(docRef[0].payload.doc.id);
      let innerRef = dayRef.collection('session').doc(index.toString())
      return this.db.firestore.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
        return transaction.get(innerRef.ref).then(function() {
          console.log("outermost")
          innerRef.valueChanges().subscribe(toRollback => {
            console.log("toRollback: " + toRollback)
            dayRef.valueChanges().subscribe(toUpdate => {
              console.log("toUpdate: " + toUpdate)
              dayRef.update({
                caloriesBurned: toUpdate["caloriesBurned"] - toRollback["caloriesBurned"], 
                sessionTime: toUpdate["sessionTime"] - toRollback["duration"] })
            })
          })
          transaction.set(innerRef.ref, value);
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

The gist is that this `dayRef.update()` call updates a collection in Firebase. Once the collection updates, the `dayRef.valueChanges()` subscription will realize there's a new value to emit and run again, which will keep updating `dayRef` repeatedly. This leads to an infinite loop.

The ideal behavior is that I subscribe to this observable, then, using the values emitted from the observable, update the Firebase collection that the observable has derived its old values from. As the subscription is still active, the `dayRef.update()` call will keep executing each time I update.

I understand that this is probably a fundamental misunderstanding of observables. What's happening here, logically, makes sense to me, but I'm not sure how else to use the values without subscribing unsure how to unsubscribe properly. I've tried running `.unsubscribe()` at the end of each observable's block, but this just unsubscribes synchronously, before the values can be emitted.

edit: with `switchMap`

```
dayRef.valueChanges().pipe(switchMap(toUpdate => 
              innerRef.valueChanges().pipe(switchMap(toRollback => 
                dayRef.update({
                  caloriesBurned: toUpdate["caloriesBurned"] - toRollback["caloriesBurned"], 
                  sessionTime: toUpdate["sessionTime"] - toRollback["duration"] })
            ))
          ))
```

Comment: Using `valueChanges` inside a transaction sounds like a bad idea.  If you need to work with a document in a transaction, you should only ever use the `transaction` object passed to the transaction handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing nested subscriptions is indeed a very bad practice. Chain rxjs operators instead.
In your example, I think switchMap would be well suited. Depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

See documentation :
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Edit :

Furthermore, try to define most of your Observable logic before the transaction. If you can, define it outside of your `updateActivity()` function.

For example :

```
        let dayRef$ = this.currentDay.pipe(
            switchMap(docRef => this.db.collection('days').doc(docRef[0].payload.doc.id))
        );
        let innerRef$ = dayRef$.pipe(
            map(dayRef => dayRef.collection('session').doc(index.toString()))
        );
```

represent your observables.

Comment: hey, I've given it a try but I can't see any real difference with switchMap. When I subscribe the pipe that I use switchMap inside, the same infinite looping effect occurs. I've appended the code to my answer but I'm still really unsure if I'm even using switchMap properly.

Comment: I think you do not yet understand how it works. When you subscribe from an observable, you switch to a synchronous context.
So the code executed in a subscribe is executed at each new value emitted.
Your first piece of code creates a new subscription for your `dayRef.valueChanges()` at each new value of `innerRef.valueChanges()`.
Can you see the problem ?

Comment: I've taken some of the processing here to a cloud function that works a lot better. The function almost works as intended, but it's stuck in an update loop still that is related to the first subscription. I've tried using switchMap to get dayRef as you've shown, but `.doc` doesn't return an observable, so the operator complains. I tried using `map` instead, but this still leads to the same effect. I still have to subscribe to `dayRef$` afterwards, so it'll still emit a new value each time I update the `day` collection.

Comment: Try to have only one subsciption for your entire process. If you have that, not only you will easily keep track of your process, but you will resolve a lot of errors.
It takes some time to adjust to this way of seeing things but once you got it, it's really worth it.